# VBA: Unhide rows which contains value in an Array from a checkbox

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have three checkboxes (Cat, Dog, Mouse) and I have the below data set in excel (Letters are columns).

```
A      B       C
Cat   Cat     Mouse
Dog   Mouse     Cat
Mouse  Mouse     Dog
Dog    Cat       Cat
```

and I have the following code:

```
Dim num As Integer

arrcriteria = Array("Cat", "Dog", "Mouse")

Set temprange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
Set temprange = Range(Range("A2"), temprange)

For Each z In temprange    
    z.EntireRow.Hidden = True    
    For num = 1 To 3    
       If Me.Controls("Checkbox" & num) Then    
          If InStr(1, z.Value, arrcriteria(num - 1), 1) = 1 Then    
              z.EntireRow.Hidden = False    
          Elseif InStr(1, z.offset(0,1).Value, arrcriteria(num - 1), 1) = 1 Then
              z.EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Elseif InStr(1, z.offset(0,2).Value, arrcriteria(num - 1), 1) = 1 Then
              z.EntireRow.Hidden = False
          Else    
              'Remain hidden    
          End If 
       End if
   Next num
```

However I want to change the code so that it hides rows when only **all** selected criteria are present in that row. For example if I select 'Cat' and 'Dog' the below is shown only:

```
 A      B       C
Dog    Mouse   Cat
Dog    Cat     Cat
```

Do you know how it can be done?

Thank you in advance

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim num         As Integer
Dim RowString   As String
Dim RowHide     As Boolean
Dim Z           As Range

arrcriteria = Array("Cat", "Dog", "Mouse")

Set temprange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)
Set temprange = Range(Range("A2"), temprange)

For Each Z In temprange

    With Z
        Z.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        RowString = .Value & .Offset(0, 1).Value & .Offset(0, 2).Value
        RowHide = False

        For num = 1 To 3
            If Me.Controls("Checkbox" & num) And _
            InStr(1, RowString, arrcriteria(num - 1), 1) = 0 _
            Then RowHide = True
        Next num

        If RowHide Then Z.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End With
Next Z
```

Comment: @Dinks123 can you flag the answer for this question as complete?